# Editing a post with a link to an external website

Tags: discussion, editing

I came across this post [QGIS Georeferencer is stretching image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174915/qgis-georeferencer-is-stretching-image) whilst searching for information on georeferencing. The question links to an external website (with adverts) which shows three screenshots.

It's a good question and answer and so I am minded to edit the post to bring the screenshots into the question itself and remove the external link. This would to stop 'link-rot', and to bring it in-house, as it were. But it this the right course of action?

I have had a look on this Meta, and Meta SE, about this, and couldn't find a clear answer?

Comment: _It's a good question and answer and so I am minded to edit the post to bring the screenshots into the question itself and remove the external link._ Do it. I'd say include the screenshots and leave the hyperlink for some sort of crediting the images; but in that case apparently the OP is also the author of them.

Comment: I have done this from time to time to keep the question up to date.  There's nothing worse than link rot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, I think that this is the correct course of action.  This means that the images will stay active (in Stack Exchange's Imgur account) even if the current linked images disappear.  Stack Exchange Imgur images are permanent, whereas images stored in user's own (usually free) accounts can disappear at any time.

The images in this Question appear to have been put there specifically for this question - they are not part of another site's content as far as I can tell - so adding those images and removing that link will ensure the images stay with that Q&A.